Understanding a bound on number of primes congruent with $a$ mod $q$
I was trying to read the the following paper on Chebyshev's bias by Rubinstein and Sarnak. But I am unable to understand the proof of Lemma 2.1. Could someone please explain how they got the expression for $\pi(x,q,a)$ from the first line? I understand Riemann-Stieltje integration is being used here, but I can't deduce the exact expression. Also how did they get the expression for $\psi(x,q,a)$? Here $c\left(q,a\right):=-1+\sum_{0\le b\le q-1,b^{2}\equiv a\mod q}1$. Thanks in advance. 

Perhaps it's better to also include a link to the article above by Rubinstein and Sarnak

By the definition of $\theta,$ as $t$ increases the expression for $\theta(t,q,a)$ jumps up by the amount $\log t$ each time when $t$ crosses another prime that satisfies the congruence condition. This establishes the equality up to an integration constant. I assume that the context, which you did not reproduce, ensures that the left hand side $\pi(x,q,a)$ is $0$ for $x=2,$ making that integration constant $0.$

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the set of primes. For the first expression, use Abel's summation formula and integration by parts $$\pi\left(x,q,a\right)=\sum_{2\le n\le x}\log n\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\left\{ p\in\mathbb{P}:p\equiv a\mod q\right\} }\left(n\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\log n}
$$$$=\frac{\theta\left(x,q,a\right)}{\log x}-\frac{\theta\left(2,q,a\right)}{\log2}-\int_{2}^{x}\theta\left(t,q,a\right)\left(\frac{1}{\log t}\right)'dt
=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{d\theta\left(t,q,a\right)}{\log t}.$$ For the second part - start with $$\psi\left(x,q,a\right)=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{p^{k}\le x,p^{k}\equiv a\mod q}\log p
=\theta\left(x,q,a\right)+\sum_{p^{2}\le x,p^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\log p $$$$ +\sum_{k\ge3}\sum_{p^{k}\le x,p^{k}\equiv a\mod q}\log p$$ and then $$\sum_{p^{2}\le x,p^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\log p=\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\sum_{p\equiv b\mod q,p\leq\sqrt{x}}\log p
=\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right).$$ Using the simplest form of Dirichlet's theorem, we get by Abel's summation $$\theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right)=\sum_{p\le\sqrt{x},p\equiv b\mod q}\log p=\left(\sum_{p\le\sqrt{x},p\equiv b\mod q}1\right)\cdot\log\sqrt{x}-\int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du
=\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\varphi\left(q\right)\log\sqrt{x}}+o\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log x}\right)\right)\cdot\log\sqrt{x}-\int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du
=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\varphi\left(q\right)}+o\left(\sqrt{x}\right)-\int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du.$$ Now, evaluate $$\int_{2}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du=\int_{2}^{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du+\int_{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sum_{p\le u,p\equiv b\mod q}1}{u}du
\ll x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\frac{u}{\log u}+o\left(\frac{u}{\log u}\right)}{u}du=x^{\frac{1}{3}}+\int_{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{\log u}+o\left(\frac{1}{\log u}\right)du
\ll\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\log x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=o\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$ hence $$\theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\varphi\left(q\right)}+o\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$ so $$\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q} \theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right)=\left(\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q} 1\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\varphi\left(q\right)}+o\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$$ and finally, since the 3rd sum is clearly negligible, we get $$\psi\left(x,q,a\right)=\theta\left(x,q,b\right)+\left(\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q} 1\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\varphi\left(q\right)}+o\left(\sqrt{x}\right).$$

Is not the last term corresponding to k \geq 3 O(x^{1/3})? Did they just write it in a weaker form? Also I don't see how to get the second term from the k=2.

@mathisfun Now that I think about it again, I'm not sure what is the best error term I know for the Dirichlet's theorem about primes in arithmetic progressions. Anyway, note that $$\sum_{p^{2}\le x,p^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\log p=\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\sum_{p\le\sqrt{x},p\equiv b\mod q}\log p
$$$$=\sum_{b^{2}\equiv a\mod q}\theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right).$$  By using the best asymptotic for the theorem, you can get the corresponding expression for $\theta\left(\sqrt{x},q,b\right)$ for all $0 \leq b \leq q-1.$ Of course, the 3rd sum ($k\geq 3$) is $O\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\log x\right)$.

@mathisfun I also recommend you take a look at Siegel-Walfisz theorem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem

I think it is O(pi(x^1/3) log x) or O(x^{1/3})

@mathisfun I've mentioned it just to made clear that it's negligible. The exact error is not important as it's much smaller than the rest, even in this rough form

I am unable to do it from here for the second term. What is the upper bound for $\theta(x,q,a)$?

@mathisfun I've added the full explanation to the answer, with the compromised error $o(\sqrt x)$. Of course, to get the error from the above paper, you must use a stronger form of the quantitive, Dirichlet's theorem, but anyways, these are the steps.
